# How does angular catch external async third party callback functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I started using AngularJS about 3 weeks ago, and started writing a simple application which gets asynchronous data from an external library (OnReceiveMessage) and then (using Angular) editing the scope in order to display and do other stuff with the message, or even reply at this message.
First i started declaring object into the app controller, and it works, but it's a mess and it's not the right thing to do.
My question is: how can i start this async client (over web socket communication) and pass the external function of this library (to send and asynchronously receive) into Angular to do stuff with it (scope, reply etc...)

external.js

```
Example:
var client = new ExtClient({params}); //not setting callbacks
Client.onMessageArrived = myCallbackHandler;
var message = new ExtMessage("Hi there");
Client.send(message);
function myCallbackHandler(message) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived");
}
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['connectionService']);
app.controller('MainController', [ '$scope', 
    function($scope) {
        //I want to catch the myCallbackHandler function async with the message
       //and use the client.send(message) with the response...
       $scope.messageTable.push({message.id, message.value}); //messageTable is bind in the view to create a table
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also think about communication between different elements of your application using $broadcast(), $emit() and $on(), on $scope or $rootScope. More:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: That's amazing, thank you!
This helps out a lot, especially when an object needs to be renewed and the event hooks get wiped out... and stay in coherence with the async nature of javascript
I wonder, is there another path elegant like this? Like in plain js, how can i handle if the new object does not fire new events?

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you want to create a service.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['connectionService'])
    .factory('messageService', function() {
        var client = new ExtClient({
            // set your params
        });

        return {
            listen: function(event, callback) {
                /* code to register a callback on an event */
                client[event] = callback;
            },
            push: function(id, value) {
                /* code to push a message */
                client.send(new ExtMessage(message));
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MainController', ['messageService' function(messageService) {
        messageService.listen('onMessageArrived', function(message) {
            console.log("onMessageArrived");
        });
        messageService.push('some id', 'some message');
    }]);
```

Comment: That's very close to be a complete answer, beside some missing parenthesis, but my external library does not cooperate. When i call client.eventhandler it expects some sort of option like "tell me the callback function when this event happen" so:
    client.onMessageArrived = myOnMessageArrivedHandler
that is located inside "listen". But when i run the code, the console in the controller never logs, but the event is fired in the factory, because if i write an inline function instead of the callback, it execute it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Without knowing much about your external library, it's tough to say what is going on. If I were troubleshooting this thing, I would use Chrome Inspector, click on the Source tab, open up the file where you define your `MainController`, and set a break point inside the callback function. Then reload the app and it should freeze at the break point you set. From there, you can examine the closure and do some testing in the console to figure out what the problem is. It may be possible that the external library has no access to the global scope, i.e. `window`, therefore no access to `console`.